# (AUTOIT) Au3Recoder failing to launch in Win7 64bit

Tags: windows, user-interface, windows-7-x64, ui-automation, autoit

I'm trying to automate few software installations. I came to know about AutoIt Au3Recoder, but its failing to launch in Win7 64bit. It through me an error message while launching

```
"MSVCR100.dll Not Found"
```

I tried with downloading the same .dll file and adding into system32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder but still I'm facing the same.

(Either I should resolve this or I should go with some other software, If you know any other software please suggest me)

Answer (score 1):

Just install the following package and this error should be gone:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632